# We do @Autowired NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring Boot 2 and it works OK. This works because NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is in applicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I checked whether NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is in the applicationConext using the code below.
But it does not find it.  Any idea?

```
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLauncher.class, args);
        Object obj = applicationContext.getBean("namedParameterJdbcTemplate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your check is wrong. Use `applicationContext.getBean(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class)` instead of the name. The bean is only available if you configured a datasource, else it will not be there.

Comment: Thanks!  applicationContext.getBean(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class) works.  But then how do we use  applicationContext.getBean(String name) which accepts String?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As that really ties your dependencies to a name which makes you need to know too much about the context. afaik the name is correct so it should find it (could be that the name is appended with a #0). You can try to get all the beans in the context and print them out (name and class) and see what the name is.